# Add labels on dynamically created textboxes

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here I have the code for create textboxes and button dynamically.problem is that I want to add labels which I want on this textboxes instead of static placeholder value .Please help me.Here is the code.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Dynamically add Textbox, Radio, Button in html 
Form using    JavaScript</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add(type) {
var element = document.createElement("input");
element.setAttribute("type", type);
element.setAttribute("value", type);
element.setAttribute("name", type);
var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
foo.appendChild(element);}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM>
<H2>Dynamically add element in form.</H2>
Select the element and hit Add to add it in form.
<BR/>
<SELECT name="element">
<OPTION value="button">Button</OPTION>
<OPTION value="text">Textbox</OPTION>
<OPTION value="radio">Radio</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<INPUT type="button" 
value="Add"    onClick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>
<span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Please try to implement the functionality you want and post question(s) here if you run into any problems :)

Comment: Not sure i even understand what kind of help you asking. If you want label elements with specified text you can add new input like you allready have one parameter. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/a25tagfg/

Comment: Ya..dis...how can I get this code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
 function add(type) {
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
    if(type=="text"){

        foo.innerHTML +="Text:<input type='text'>"
    }else{
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.setAttribute("type", type);
        element.setAttribute("value", type);
        element.setAttribute("name", type);
        foo.appendChild(element);
    }

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1e3g8va/1/)

To short down the code

```
function add(type,label) {

   var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

  foo.innerHTML +=""+label+":<input type='"+type+"' value="+label+">";

}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxju9cqp/1/)